# I'm receiving "The Overflow" newsletter but I have never subscribed

Tags: support, email, the-overflow

Recently I've received the first installment of "The Overflow" newsletter.

The email claims that I'd be receiving this because I have subscribed. I did no such thing. The number of email newsletters that I have actively and willingly subscribed to in my life is *very* close to zero.

What you did is: Sneaking in a new email preference called "The Overflow" behind my back and defaulted it to "on". That is not the same thing as me subscribing to anything.

[image: Screenshot of the email preferences]

I get it, you want to give your new newsletter some traction, but this is not the way to do that. **This is spamming.** And you guys should not be spamming people.

Please review your processes around people's communication preferences. This is not okay *at all*.